# activerecord-sqlserver-adapter on Ubuntu

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I followed the instructions found here to get my rails app to communicate with SQL Server on Ubuntu 10.04

http://web.archive.org/web/20100305130227/http://wiki.github.com/rails-sqlserver/2000-2005-adapter/platform-installation-ubuntu-2

All the tests documented there have passes except the when I try script/sconsole
I was able to make a db connection in irb

In my app I have a model **Report.rb**

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name "dbo.tvAllWorkstreams_Summary_AllReports_Sel"
end
```

in script/console I get the following

```
>>Report.count  
NameError: uninitialized constant Report  
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load_missing_constant'  
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'  
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:92:in `const_missing'  
from (irb):1
```

Here is my configuration:

Connecting to MS SQL Server 2000

**database.yml**

development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: odbc
  dsn: production
  username: xxxx
  password: xxxx

in **environment.rb** I added

config.gem 'activerecord-sqlserver-adapter', :version => '2.3.8'

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

actionmailer (2.3.8)
actionpack (2.3.8)
activerecord (2.3.8)
activerecord-sqlserver-adapter (2.3.8)
activeresource (2.3.8)
activesupport (2.3.8)
rack (1.1.0)
rails (2.3.8)
rake (0.8.7)
sqlite3-ruby (1.3.0)

what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this error has anything to do with the SqlServer adapter, for those you will get cannot find odbc errors or unable to connect to the data source.  It is not seeing the report model here.  Is the report model in `app/models/report.rb` ?  I have this when I am namespacing and forget to put the namespace before the model name which would be.

```
NameSpace::Report.count
```

Comment: yeah, file is just in 
app/models/Report.rb

Comment: Went back and figured it out.  I had Report.rb instead of report.rb